# Возможно ли подключиться к файлу который у меня на pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

Допустим у меня есть питон файл на компе и файл .txt на pythonanywhere, как мне и вообще возможно *подключиться* к этому файлу и получить возможность читать его и сохранять новое в него?
Я два часа гуглил и не смог найти ответ на мой вопрос, помогите пожалуйста.
Желательно показать код для подключения к нему и записи нового в него...

Comment: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/UploadingAndDownloadingFiles/

Comment: @GrAnd Эт не совсем то что мне нужно...

Comment: Ну пожалуйста, я очень жду ответа, кто-нибудь подскажите

Comment: 1 - делаете веб-приложение, которое будет уметь редактировать этот файл, редактируете файл через него. Напрямую "подключиться к файлу" невозможно. 2 - находите ftp хостинг, подключаете ftp как диск в систему, редактируете как вам удобно. 3 - используйте в качестве онлайн редактора "файла" что-то типа pastebin или github gists, из pythonanywhere получаете данные с этого сервиса.

Comment: @insolor а есть хостинг где можно попроще? не питонанивер